# Does Fuseki --update need extra writing permissions?

Tags: fuseki

I tested Fuseki-Server on Ubuntu:

./fuseki-server loc=/data/ds --update /Test-ds

but it runs only in read-only mode (INFO Running in read-only mode for /Test-ds).

Should I set up extra permissions? Files in /data/ds were created Ok.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the admin interface only works with localhost for security 
reasons. So, we need to modify the shiro.ini file (/fuseki/run/shiro.ini) and uncomment the line that allows any access. I'm still looking for examples to set up a more sophisticated security.